# Android - Threads and callback to activity

Tags: android, multithreading, callback, fragment

I have an activity and a fragment.
This fragment starts a thread which lasts 3 seconds and then calls a callback method on the activity.

if configuration is changed (i.e orientation changed), my actiivty gets recreated with new references, but the thread still has the old reference, causing a mess.

Any idea to solve this? thanks

Answer (score 0):

how about use service instead thread?

reference here :

https://github.com/stephanenicolas/robospice/wiki/Starter-guide

if you want communicate a fragment or activity between thread. use interface like listener. for example, if activity recreate or something change, notify to thread, change listener to new activity.

Comment: thanks for the advice, the fact is that i thought of services as advanced components, which can be used for more advanced purposes than this. Do threads really work bad for this?

Comment: maybe yes. you can search for that.

Answer (score 0):

You can use an AsyncTask instead of thread. Call task.cancel() in your onDestroy() method of the activity.

Hence your activity wont get getting any callback if the onDestroy() method has been already called.

If you insist on using thread then may be you can add a check like this in your callback method

```
if(getActivity() == null || getActivity().isFinishing())
   return;
```

Comment: The problem is that i need to execute the callback method, but since i have this problem i must redirect the old references to the new ones... Maybe threads are not good for this purposes...

Comment: See any ways the new activity which is recreated will again create the  thread so you will get the callback.